# Subtract pandas dataframes while leaving some columns intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
data1 = """
idx, stat, val
1, 1, 5
2, 1, 10
3, 2, 15
4, 3, 20
"""
data2 = """
idx, stat, val
2, 1, 8
4, 5, 16
"""
```

(sorry - I don't know how to code this easily in pandas - I would read them in from csv in real life).

I would like to subtract these two dataframes so that only the val column is subtracted (in real life these are station coordinates). The result should be NaN if only one of the two dataframes has the respective index value (column idx in the ascii format). Also ok if non-matching rows are immediately removed (I would call dropna afterwards anyhow).

Hence, my desired result would be:

```
desired = """
idx, stat, val
1, 1, NaN
2, 1, 2
3, 2, NaN
4, 3, 4
"""
```

In principle `data1.sub(data2)` works nicely -- except that I cannot see a way how to "protect" the stat column from the subtraction. I also tried `data1.sub(data2['val'], axis=0)`, but this messed up the row matching which is automatically performed in `data1.sub(data2)`. A workaround is to re-substitute the stat column(s) afterwards with the original values from `data1`, but this seems rather clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1.set_index(['idx','stat'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index('idx', inplace=True)

print (df1.sub(df2[['val']]))
          val
idx stat     
1   1     NaN
2   1     2.0
3   2     NaN
4   3     4.0

print (df1.sub(df2[['val']]).reset_index())
   idx  stat  val
0    1     1  NaN
1    2     1  2.0
2    3     2  NaN
3    4     3  4.0
```

If `idx` are indexes in both `df`:

```
print (df1)
     stat  val
idx           
1       1    5
2       1   10
3       2   15
4       3   20

print (df2)
     stat  val
idx           
2       1    8
4       5   16

df1.set_index('stat', append=True, inplace=True)
print (df1.sub(df2[['val']]).reset_index())
   idx  stat  val
0    1     1  NaN
1    2     1  2.0
2    3     2  NaN
3    4     3  4.0
```